# I want to hide div if user click on dot icon and wanna show other div instead of first one

Tags: html, reactjs, onclick, hide, show

[image]

I want to hide div if user click on dot icon and want to show other div instead of first one.

Please look at this website section image i want to hide this div on click if user click on dot icon.I dispatched two picture one code and other its output in the  browser.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please have a read of the [help] and the [ask] section in particular - I would also recommend you take the [tour]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also please think about the most important tag and include that. In this case React is PRETTY important